# Styling checkbox and anchor tag next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox and then i have an anchor tag that displays some text and then will have chevron button to toggle either up or down. Currently my checkbox and anchor tag are on seperate lines and i wanted to have my anchor tag next to my checkbox. How can i style the below code to make it possible.

```
<header class="refine-menu-subheader" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline;">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   [checked]="item.isActive"
                                   (change)="">
                            <span class="text-body"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <a class="refine-menu-collapse" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline;" data-toggle="collapse" data-collapse-icon="ChevronDown" data-expand-icon="ChevronUp" aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="item.id" [attr.data-target]="'#'+item.id">
                        <h3 class="refine-menu-subtitle">{{item.name}}</h3>
                        <span class="win-icon refine-menu-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Flex** for this quite easily. All you need is `align-items: baseline;` to center the elements' baselines. `flex-direction: row;` is the default direction, but I left it in there so there is no confusion.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<header class="refine-menu-subheader">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" 
             [checked]="item.isActive" 
             (change)="">
      <span class="text-body"></span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <a class="refine-menu-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-collapse-icon="ChevronDown" data-expand-icon="ChevronUp" aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="item.id" [attr.data-target]="'#'+item.id">
    <h3 class="refine-menu-subtitle">{{item.name}}</h3>
    <span class="win-icon refine-menu-icon"></span>
  </a>
</header>
```

Comment: This work and now the checkbox and anchor tag are both on same line. But now i am getting the collapse icon right next to <h3>. is there a way to have that positioned to the right of the div instead of next to the word?

Comment: Can you share me your (new) code so I can look at it?

Comment: I updated my post. i basically added your style from the header class for both the header and the anchor tag so i can get both the text and icon to appear on the same line.

Comment: I don't see a collapse icon because you haven't included the link to the library that you're using for icons in your code above.

Comment: The library that i am using is not available online but you can add in any icon you want for visual reference.

Comment: This is what it looks like to me, I didn't change any of the CSS, I've only added the icon from Font Awesome: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/yv9Lxjo4/41/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yv9Lxjo4/42/ I updated what you have. lets assume header has a width of 250px and height of 45px... i would like for the icon to be aligned to the far right of the div/header

Comment: Here you go: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/yv9Lxjo4/44/). I marked what was added with comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can set both the `.checkbox` and `.refine-menu-collapse` to be `display: inline-block` and that should be enough to do what you need. It may be a good idea to wrap them both in a div though in case this causes some unexpected behaviour to other elements around it.

Comment: I did try wrapping both in a div and setting the display to inline-block for both classes but still didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen or at least the entirety of the CSS for all of the markup you've provided above?